# tricky user profile issue on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine

Tags: hyper-v, user-profiles, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-manager, cas

Need some help with a tricky user profile issue on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine acting as a CAS server.

Here's the scenario:

I'm using Hyper-V manager on another Windows Server 2012 R2 to connect to the CAS server VM.
When I try to log in, I get a frustrating error message: "The User Profile Service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded."
This is preventing me from accessing the CAS server! Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the user’s profile and recreate it?